# Store floating point number into long type

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop counter in Java, which only supports integer/long counter type, but I need a floating point counter. I was wondering is there a way to store a floating point number into integer or long type, then recover the original value from integer/long type without losing precision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Double.doubleToLongBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29) and [`Double.longBitsToDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29) should do the trick if it's a `double`. There are analogous methods on `Float` for ints.

Answer (score 2):

Class `Float` provides the methods you need:

```
int intValue = Float.floatToIntBits(floatValue);
int floatValue2 = Float.intToFloatBits(intValue)
// floatValue2 == floatValue
```

The same methods are available for double types too (see class `Double`)